# Testar números primos em C

Tags: c, matemática

Estou tentando desenvolver em C um programa no qual o usuário coloque uma sequência de números e o mesmo deve determinar se os números são primos ou não.

Segue o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {


    int num1, num2, i;
    char op;

    do {

      printf("\nInforme um numero: ");
      scanf("%i", &num1);

      printf("\nInforme um numero: ");
      scanf("%i", &num2);

        for (i=num1; i<=num2; i++) {

            if (i % 1 == 0 && i % i == 0) {

                printf("\n%i - Primos!", i);

            } else {

                printf("\n%i - Nao primos!", i);

            }
        }

     printf("\nDeseja calcular outra sequencia de numeros? ");
     scanf("%s", &op);

    } while (op == 's' || op == 'S');

    return(0);
}
```

Onde estou errando? Eu coloco uma sequência de 1 até 10 e no resultado todos são primos.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor sua pergunta Marcielli?Não entendi a parte  que você diz que tem que ler uma sequencia de números!!

Comment: Desculpe, mas se isso é material do seu curso, você não deveria vir buscar no site alguém para resolver para você. Com certeza a resposta está no livro usado no curso ou mesmo com algum colega que você possa estudar junto. O erro é bem claro para quem já passou por isso mas insistir até encontrar o erro faz parte do aprendizado.

Comment: Sim. É assim... Tenho que pedir 2 numeros pro usuario. Entre o primeiro e o segundo eu devo fazer o teste. Exemplo: Ele pode pedir de 5 à 30, então de 5 à 30 eu tenho que testar e dizer os que são primos e os que não são.

Comment: Ah sim, é minha primeira vez nesse site... Não busco por respostas prontas não, apenas dicas do que possa estar errado. Talvez eu tenha me expressado errado na pergunta. Estou aqui pra aprender, só que realmente não estou entendendo porque não esta dando certo. Mas ok, se esse tipo de pergunta não puder ser feita aqui eu entendo! Obrigada mesmo assim. ;)

Comment: Análise melhor as condições do seu ciclo de repetição for! Pense matematicamente e rascunhe em um papel um esboço matemático!! Pelo que eu entendi você deve indicar quais são os números primos entre o primeiro numero lido e segundo certo?

Comment: Ah, ok. Vou fazer isso aqui...Talvez se eu fizer no papel eu ganhe uma visão melhor do problema né? rs Sim, isso mesmo! Obrigada *-*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que este código não está testando se os números são primos. A expressão `i % i == 0` dá uma boa indicação que tem algo faltando aí. Esta expressão sempre será verdadeira, afinal o resto de um número divido por ele sempre é zero. E a expressão `i % 1 == 0` sempre é verdadeira. Todo número divido por 1 tem resto 0. Então ela é desnecessária.

A principal mudança que eu fiz foi criar um laço interno que tenta fazer todas divisões possíveis entre 2 e o número anterior ao que está se tentando testar. Se uma só divisão tiver resto zero, ele não precisa continuar comparando. Se ele parar no mesmo número que está sendo testado significa que nenhuma divisão deu resto 0, então é primo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1, num2, i, j;
    char op;
    do {
        printf("\nInforme um numero: ");
        scanf("%i", &num1);
        printf("\nInforme um numero: ");
        scanf("%i", &num2);
        for (i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
            for (j = 2; j < i; j++) if (i % j == 0) break;
            if (i == j) printf("\n%i - Primos!", i);
            else printf("\n%i - Nao primos!", i);
        }
        printf("\nDeseja calcular outra sequencia de numeros? ");
        scanf("%s", &op);
    } while (op == 's' || op == 'S');
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/9D7PJm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mnumrmdj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Prime2.c).

Tem como otimizar isto, mas como está aprendendo assim tá bom, melhor não complicar.

Comment: Ah sim, um for dentro de outro...Vou pegar linha por linha e entender agora como faz. Obrigada mesmo! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Recentemente tinha feito um exercício desse (só que além de falar se é primo ou não tinha que exibir a soma dos pares, impares e primos) , também faço ADS rs, bom, dei uma editada no meu para lhe servir, acho que ficou mais simples de entender e ficou assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>
main(void) // void, para não precisar do return 0;
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,""); // permite colocar acentos
    int num1, num2, num, cont, isPrimo;
    char op;
    do
    {
        isPrimo = 0; // é um bool binário, onde 0 não é primo e um é primo
        printf("Número Inicial: ");
        scanf("%i", &num1);
        printf("Número Final: ");
        scanf("%i", &num2);

        for(num = num1; num < num2; num ++)
        { //vai do num1 ao num2 e armazena o valor atual da sequência em num
            for(cont = 1; cont < num; cont ++)
                if(num % cont == 0) /*compara se num é divisivel pela sequencia de 1 até ele mesmo
                                      e atribui isso ao bool, para verificarmos depois*/
                    isPrimo += 1; /* aumenta o valor, se ele for primo será 1, pois número primo é 
                                    divísel por um e por ele mesmo, porém comecei o cont com 1, então se o 
                                    número for primo ele entrará no if apenas uma vez, deixando isPrimo = 1, formando um bool*/
            if(isPrimo == 1) // comparo se o bool é verdadeiro (1) e imprimo que é primo
                printf("%3i é primo.\n", num);
            else // se nao ele não é primo
                printf("%3i não é primo.\n", num);
            isPrimo = 0; //redefino o bool
        }
        printf("\nDeseja calcular outra sequencia de numeros? ");
        scanf("%s", &op);
        system("cls");
    }while(op == 's' || op == 'S');
    system("pause");

}
```

Espero que tenha ficado mais simples para entender rsr, nem ia responder a pergunta porque já está aqui á muito tempo e já tem resposta, mas são lógicas diferentes e talvez você entenda essa melhor.

Comment: Ah, que legal. Obrigada. Vou dar uma estudada no jeito que você fez também. ;)