# Codigo para calcular os primeiros N numeros primos em C?

Tags: c

Primeiro, tenho isso aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

   int i=13,w=0,k;

   for(k=i-1;k!=1;k--){

      if(i%k==0){w=1; break;}        
   }               

   if(w==0){ printf("\n%d eh primo",i); }

   system("pause");    
   return 0;    
}
```

Nesse caso particular, calcula se 13 é primo ou não. 
Agora, quero fazer um para exibir os primeiros "n" primeiros primos, fiz isso, mas não funciona como eu esperava:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

   int i=2,w=0,k,j=1;

   while(1==1){    

      for(k=i-1;k!=1;k--){

         if(i%k==0){w=1; break;}          
      }       

      if(w==0){ j++; printf("\n%d eh primo",i); }

      if(j==7) break;

      i++;             
   }

   system("pause");    
   return 0;    
}
```

Esse seria para exibir os 7 primeiros primos, mas só exibe 2 e 3. Por que isso? Criei um inteiro `j` para ser incrementado sempre que primo acontecer. Quando ele virar 7 o laço para.

Fico grato com quem me ajudar. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Qual dessas você acha que é a mais adequada pra responder isto? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84040/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85565/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85562/101, tem outros.

Comment: Não acho que a pergunta dele seja duplicata de nenhuma dessas que você sugeriu, @bigown. O caso dele é diferente.

Answer (score 5):

este erro está acontecendo porque quando o w recebe 1 ele não retorna pro valor inicial que é 0. tente desse jeito.

```
for(k = i - 1, w = 0; k != 1; k++)
{
     if(i%k==0)
     {
         w = 1;
         break;
     }
}
```

assim quando retornar pro loop o valor de w será 0 novamente.

Comment: Funcionou. Era isso mesmo. Vlw!

Comment: Tem como eu te positivar?

Answer (score 0):

Código para executar uma busca de números primos em um intervalo determinado pelo usuário.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
int a,b,f,i,r,min,max,z;
printf("Digite dois valores para ser calculado os numeros primos dentro do intervalo:\n");
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
if (a<b){
    min=a; max=b;
    }
else {
    min=b; max=a;
    }
i=2; z=0; f=0;
printf("\nValores entre %d e %d:\n",min,max);
while(min<=max) {
    while(min>=i) {
        r=min%i;
    if (r==0)
        z=z+1; i=i+1;
    }
    if (z==1){
        f=f+1;  if (f==1)
                    printf("(%d",min);
            else if (f>1)
                    printf(", %d",min);
    }
    min=min+1; i=2; z=0;
    }
if (f>0)
    printf(")\n\n");
else
    printf("Sem valores nesse intervalo.\n\n");
getchar();
}
```

Esse código é executado mesmo que o primeiro numero digitado seja maior ou igual que o segundo numero.